# Spring boot don't let me create a repository without database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I've created a project on Spring Boot.

I've two providers extending the same Abstract provider, and i load on startup the one i'm interested in via Spring Profile.

One of the providers is based on JPA, the other have his interface implemented where i make calls to webservices.

This is the interface of the provider wich i don't want to use databases:

```
package net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.massilia.provider;


import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.contract.IProductRepository;
import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.massilia.model.MassiliaProduct;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@Profile("massilia")
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MassiliaProductRepository extends IProductRepository<MassiliaProduct,String> {

}
```

And this is the interface for the provider using database :

```
package net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.local.provider;


import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.contract.IProductRepository;
import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.local.model.Product;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Profile("local")
@Repository
public interface MonBoProductRepository extends IProductRepository<Product,String> {

    @Query("select p.variants from Product p where p.ean = :ean")
    List<Product> findVariantByEan(@Param("ean") String ean);

    @Query("select p.companions from Product p where p.ean = :ean")
    List<Product> findCompanionByEan(@Param("ean") String ean);

}
```

They extend this interface in common :

```
package net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.contract;

import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.model.AbstractProduct;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IProductRepository<T extends AbstractProduct,ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
    @RestResource(path = "byEAN")
    T findByEan(@Param("ref") Integer ean);

    T findProductByEan(@PathVariable ID ean);

    List<T> findVariantByEan(@PathVariable ID ean);

    List<T> findCompanionByEan(@PathVariable ID ean);
}
```

The provider wich isn't using database have an implementation, for job reasons, i can't show you the implementation, but it calls inside webservices

Like my providers, i've two models, extending the same abstract class.

One is annoted with @Entity,@Id and co, and i don't want to add this annotations on the other class, because for me, i've precised that i didn't want any database by asking none in the `application-${profile}.properties`.

This is this Model i used with the bdd :

```
package net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.local.model;

import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.model.AbstractProduct;
import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.model.AbstractProductCharacteristic;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;



@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
@Profile("local")
public class Product extends AbstractProduct {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Product.class);

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name="products_to_variants",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="productEan"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="productEanVariant")
    )
    private List<Product> variants;

    @ManyToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name="products_to_companions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="productEan"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="productEanCompanion")
    )
    private List<Product> companions;

    @Column(name = "accroche")
    private String accroche;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ean", unique = false)
    private String ean;

    @Column(name = "descriptif")
    private String descriptif;

    @Column(name = "libelle")
    @NotEmpty
    private String libelle;

    @Column(name = "oldPrice")
    private String oldPrice;

    @Column(name = "price")
    @NotEmpty
    //@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10)
    private String price;

    @Column(name = "stock")
    private String stock;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ean" )
    protected List<ProductCharacteristic> characteristics;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product" )
    @NotEmpty
    protected List<ProductVisual> visuals;

    public List<Product> getVariants() {
        return variants;
    }

    public void setVariants(List<Product> variants) {
        this.variants = variants;
    }

    public List<Product> getCompanions() {
        return companions;
    }

    public void setCompanions(List<Product> companions) {
        this.companions = companions;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccroche() {
        return accroche;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAccroche(String accroche) {
        this.accroche = accroche;
    }


    @Override
    public String getEan() {
        return ean;
    }

    public void setRef(String ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOldPrice() {
        return oldPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOldPrice(String oldPrice) {
        this.oldPrice = oldPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public List<? extends AbstractProductCharacteristic> getCharacteristics() {
        return characteristics;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductVisual> getVisuals() {
        return visuals;
    }

    public String getDescriptif() {
        return this.descriptif;
    }

    public void setDescriptif(String descriptif) {
        this.descriptif=descriptif;
    }
}
```

This is the model i don't want to use with a database:

```
package net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.massilia.model;


import net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.model.AbstractProduct;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


@Profile("massilia")
public class MassiliaProduct extends AbstractProduct {

    @Override
    public String getEan() { return this.ean; }

    @Override
    public String getLibelle() { return this.libelle; }

    @Override
    public String getPrice() { return this.price; }

    @Override
    public String getAccroche() { return this.accroche; }

    @Override
    public String getOldPrice() { return oldPrice; }

    @Override
    public String getStock() { return stock; }

    @Override
    public String getDescriptif() {
        return descriptif;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MassiliaCharacteristic> getCharacteristics() {
        return (List<MassiliaCharacteristic>)characteristics;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MassiliaProductVisual> getVisuals() {
        return (List<MassiliaProductVisual>)visuals;
    }

}
```

They share this model in common :

```
package net.worldline.mst.metro.ds.core.model;

import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport;
import org.springframework.hateoas.core.Relation;

import java.util.List;



@Relation(value = "product", collectionRelation = "product")

public abstract class AbstractProduct extends ResourceSupport {

    protected String ean;

    protected String libelle;

    protected String accroche;

    protected String price;

    protected String oldPrice;

    protected String stock;

    protected String descriptif;

    protected List<? extends AbstractProductCharacteristic> characteristics;

    protected List<? extends AbstractProductVisual> visuals;

    public abstract  String getEan();

    public abstract String getLibelle();

    public abstract String getPrice();

    public abstract String getAccroche();

    public abstract String getOldPrice();

    public abstract String getStock();

    public abstract List<? extends AbstractProductCharacteristic> getCharacteristics();

    public abstract List<? extends AbstractProductVisual> getVisuals();

    public abstract String getDescriptif();

    public void setEan(String ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setAccroche(String accroche) {
        this.accroche = accroche;
    }

    public void setOldPrice(String oldPrice) {
        this.oldPrice = oldPrice;
    }

    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void setCharacteristics(List<? extends AbstractProductCharacteristic> characteristics) {
        this.characteristics = characteristics;
    }

    public void setVisuals(List<? extends AbstractProductVisual> visuals) {
        this.visuals = visuals;
    }

    public void setDescriptif(String descriptif) {
        this.descriptif = descriptif;
    }


}
```

In the application`-${profile}.properties`, i precise :

`spring.datasource.platform = hsqldb for the jpa instance`.

```
spring.datasource.platform = none for the instance where i call my webservices.
```

My problem is simple : i was hoping spring letting me do what i want by implementing the repository, but when i launch my server, spring say that my objects are not managed, so if i don't add @Entity to my model, it doesn't want to run.

So why Spring data looks like it loads JPA repository by default ?

Comment: If you "forget to precise" you can use the edit function for your post. And if you do this you can mark files content as code, this improves readability. Showing your classes might help too.  And I am sure you are hoping, not hopping ;-)

Comment: Yeah ... if i could, but i need 10 reputation for adding images, i've prepared screenshots for nothing :/

Comment: Add them as text and format as code ...

Comment: It's pictures of diagrams of my class, i think it's more understandable.

Comment: Marged I've did like you suggest :) thanks for helping the understanding ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a human error in fact.

I'v forgotten a `spring.datasource.platform = hsqldb` in my `application.properties` file.

I wasn't looking at it cause i'm using spring profiles so i was looking at my `application-massilia.properties` wich contains `spring.datasource.platform = none` and is listened now cause i've deleted the duplicate in the other file.